# How to draw 3d vectors in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to draw several vectors in a 3D plot. The co-ordinates of the start and end point are columns in a data file. In 2D, I plot vectors by:

```
plot 'data.dat' u 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors
```

How can I do it in 3D?

**Edit**

I am trying to draw these vectors on top of a surface. When I try this:

```
set hidden3d
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set zlabel "z"
set dgrid3d 10,10 qnorm 2
file = "surface.dat"

splot file u 1:2:3 with lines, file 1:2:3:($4-$1):($5-$2):($6-$3) with vectors
```

I get the surface, but not the vectors. (The vectors are out of the plane of the surface, like normals.)

[image: Output]

Comment: We don't have your data. So, we cannot reproduce it and we don't know how it should look like. Please post a complete, minimal, reproducible example. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any search at all? Have you checked the gnuplot homepage or gnuplot documentation?

From `help vectors`:

> `The 2D vectors style draws a vector from (x,y) to (x+xdelta,y+ydelta). The 3D vectors style is similar, but requires six columns of basic data. In both cases, an additional input column (5th in 2D, 7th in 3D) may be used to provide variable (per-datapoint) color information. (see linecolor and rgbcolor variable). A small arrowhead is drawn at the end of each vector.

```
 4 columns:  x  y  xdelta  ydelta
 6 columns:  x  y  z  xdelta  ydelta  zdelta
```

... and further down...

> 

Example:

```
  plot 'file.dat' using 1:2:3:4 with vectors head filled lt 2
  splot 'file.dat' using 1:2:3:(1):(1):(1) with vectors filled head lw 2
```

Hence, depending on your columns:

```
splot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3:($4-$1):($5-$2):($6-$3) with vectors
```

Comment: For a 3D plot the command must be `splot` rather than `plot`.

Comment: @Ethan, of course! Thank you for the hint! I was too focussed on z and dz.